# Error Assessing Image Quality in Tkinter Application

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an Image Quality Assessment application where I encounter the following error: "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)" during the assessment process. This occurs when loading images and waiting for the results. Surprisingly, even using the same image doesn't resolve the error.

I've attempted to use the same image to see if the error persists, but unfortunately, it does. I've also checked the array shapes and reviewed the relevant code section without success.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Run the application.

2. Load an image using the "Load Image" button.

3. Load a reference image using the "Load Reference Image" button.

4. Adjust the sliders for "Weights," "Wavelet Scale," and "Kernel Size."

5. Click the "Assess Image Quality" button. 6. Encounter the "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)" error.

```
    # Get parameters from sliders
    weights = self.weights_slider.get()
    wavelet_scale = int(self.wavelet_scale_slider.get())
    kernel_size = int(self.kernel_size_slider.get())

    # Calculate metrics
    stability = self.calculate_structural_stability(self.image, wavelet_scale=wavelet_scale)
    ssim_value, _ = ssim(self.image, self.reference_image, win_size=(min(self.image.shape[0], self.image.shape[1], 7),)*2, full=True)

    texture_features = self.calculate_texture_features(self.image, kernel_size)
    kurt = kurtosis(self.image.flatten())

    # Apply customizable weights
    normalized_weights = self.normalize_metrics(weights)
    weighted_metrics = np.multiply([ssim_value, stability, texture_features, kurt], normalized_weights)
    score = np.sum(weighted_metrics)

    # Calculate metric values and statistical test
    metric_values_image = [ssim_value, stability, texture_features, kurt]
    p_values = []

    for i, metric_value in enumerate(metric_values_image):
        # Extract metric values from the reference image
        metric_values_reference = [self.calculate_structural_stability(self.reference_image, wavelet_scale=wavelet_scale),
                                   ssim(self.reference_image, self.image, win_size=(min(self.image.shape[0], self.image.shape[1], 7),)*2, full=True)[1],
                                   self.calculate_texture_features(self.reference_image, kernel_size),
                                   kurtosis(self.reference_image.flatten())]

        # Perform paired t-test against the reference image
        _, p_value = ttest_rel([metric_value], metric_values_reference[i])
        p_values.append(p_value)

    # Display metric values and statistical test results
    self.ax[1].clear()
    self.ax[1].bar(['SSIM', 'Stability', 'Texture', 'Kurtosis'], metric_values_image, color='skyblue')

    # Display statistical test results
    for i, p_value in enumerate(p_values):
        self.ax[1].text(i, metric_values_image[i] + 0.05, f'p={p_value:.4f}', ha='center', va='bottom', fontsize=8, color='red')

    # Display images
    self.display_images()

    self.canvas.draw()

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error assessing image quality: {e}")

def calculate_structural_stability(self, image, wavelet_filter='db1', wavelet_scale=1):
    try:
        coeffs = pywt.dwt2(image, wavelet_filter)
        detail_coeffs = [np.abs(pywt.dwt2(coeff, wavelet_filter)[0]) for coeff in coeffs]

        m, n = image.shape[:2]  # Use image.shape[:2] to get the height and width
        stability = np.mean([np.prod(coeff.shape) / (m * n) for coeff in detail_coeffs])
        return stability
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error calculating structural stability: {e}")
        return 0.0
```

Comment: If there is an error, can you please post the full traceback? Also using `except Exception` isn't advised as you don't get a traceback and you might catch exceptions that you would rather be thrown.